# mongodb aggregate in vb.net no results

Tags: .net, vb.net, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I´m trying to user aggregation framework in VB.NET for mongodb as an alternative to MAP reduce. My Collection has a lot of documents like this

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("54a9542e32219b1894f38199"),
  "sesion" : "vw01q45m4c5ir45opjhncun-04012015155437",
  "prio" : 0,
  "ptun" : 78.48,
  "meta" : {
    "id_array" : 0,
    "deption" : "Main Type 1",
    "des" : "MAL",
    "reg" : "sub type 1",
    "princ" : "78,48",
    "Xref" : "ref external ID",
    "XNRF" : false
  },
  "hora" : new Date("4/1/2015 15:54:38")
}
```

I want to get for a definied "id_array" field all objects grouped in this way. For the same "deption","reg"  fields the document with lower ptun, but I get 0 results.

My code (I am really newbie to this framework). any help will be really appreciated

```
valorint = 52
        Dim operacionmatch2 = New BsonDocument() From { _
            {"$match", New BsonDocument() From { _
                {"meta.id_array", valorint}}}}


        Dim groupFamiliesOperation2 = New BsonDocument() From { _
         {"$group", New BsonDocument() From { _
             {"_id", New BsonDocument() From { _
              {"deption", "$meta.deption"}, {"reg", "$meta.reg"} _
             }}, _
             {"Minimo", New BsonDocument() From { _
                 {"$min", "$meta.ptun"} _
             }}}}}


        Dim sortidOperation = New BsonDocument() From { _
            {"$sort", New BsonDocument() From { _
                {"id_array", 1} _
            }} _
        }


        Dim j As AggregateResult

        j = transactions.Aggregate(operacionmatch2, groupFamiliesOperation2, sortidOperation)
        Console.WriteLine(" inicia consulta " & Now())

        For Each jj In j.ResultDocuments
            Dim b = 3
            Console.WriteLine(jj.ToBsonDocument())
        Next
```